# CLion WSL ssh session with x11

Tags: ssh, x11, clion

I am trying to do c++ development with SDL2 in CLion on windows with WSL. I was using Cygwin but I really want access to Valgrind so linux it is. WSL seems to work except I forgot I need X11 forwarding over ssh sessions (which WSL uses). I have Xming all installed and set up and I can manually get x11 forwarding to work but it doesn't want to work when running the project through CLion. I have tried adding the `export DISPLAY=:0` in the .bashrc. Project runs just fine but with now X11 window popping up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added `setenv("DISPLAY", "127.0.0.1:0", true);` into my main function and it works fine.

Comment: Wow so simple. Thanks :)

Comment: it might also work when adding the environment variable `DISPLAY=localhost:0` to the launch configuration